# Как загрузить сторонние пакеты в Maven проект

Tags: java, maven, jsoup

Только сегодня установил Maven (полистал официальную документацию и немного погуглил, разумеется). Решил использовать библиотеку Jsoup в своем проекте. Создаю проект командой

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Добавляю зависимость в pom.xml (с сайта Jsoup):

```
<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Редактирую файл `src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java`:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String HTMLSTring = ""
                + ""
                + ""
                + "JSoup Example"
                + ""
                + ""
                + ""
                + "HelloWorld"
                + ""
                 + "";

        Document html = Jsoup.parse(HTMLSTring);
        String title = html.title();
        String h1 = html.body().getElementsByTag("h1").text();

        System.out.println("Input HTML String to JSoup :" + HTMLSTring);
        System.out.println("After parsing, Title : " + title);
        System.out.println("Afte parsing, Heading : " + h1);

       // JSoup Example 2 - Reading HTML page from URL
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
            title = doc.title();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Jsoup Can read HTML page from URL, title : " + title);

    // JSoup Example 3 - Parsing an HTML file in Java
    //Document htmlFile = Jsoup.parse("login.html", "ISO-8859-1"); // wrong
        Document htmlFile = null;
        try {
            htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("login.html"), "ISO-8859-1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // right
        title = htmlFile.title();
        Element div = htmlFile.getElementById("login");
        String cssClass = div.className(); // getting class form HTML element

        System.out.println("Jsoup can also parse HTML file directly");
        System.out.println("title : " + title);
        System.out.println("class of div tag : " + cssClass);
    }
}
```

Собираю проект командой

```
mvn package
```

Запускаю скомпилированный и упакованный JAR командой:

```
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

Возбуждается исключение `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Как загрузить Jsoup пакет (в центральном репозитории Maven он найден) и импортировать его классы ?

Answer (score 0):

Запуск валится по причине того, что ты не указал библиотеку `Jsoup` в classpath'е (параметр `cp`). В этом случае тебе также придётся добавлять зависимости `Jsoup` в classpath. Но, к счастью, `Jsoup` ни от чего не зависит. Поэтому твой запуск превратится примерно в следующее

```
java -cp "target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;${путь_до_jsoup}/jsoup.jar" com.mycompany.app.App
```

Если же ты хочешь упаковать всё в один jar'ник, чтобы запускать так, как ты указал в вопросе, то можно воспользоваться плагином `maven-assembly-plugin` примерно так:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
      <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Более подробно можно прочитать про это в [оригинале ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574650/5506820)

Однако лучше использовать первый вариант, т.к. при сваливании по принципу `всё в один` может возникнуть конфликт ресурсов.

Comment: У меня только один архив в проекте: my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Как должен появиться jsoup.jar ?

Comment: @Антон `maven` выкачивает их с удаленного репозитория в локальный  при сборке проекта. `Jsoup` в удаленном репозитории лежит в  http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/.  Локальный репозиторий для `windows` обычно лежит в `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository`, соответственно `JSoup` в ней будет в `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.11.3`

Comment: Запускаю такую команду java -cp "target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar; /home/anton/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar" com.mycompany.app.App и выдает ошибку Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.app.App

Comment: @Антон попробуй `java -cp "target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;/home/anton/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.11.3/jsoup-1.11.3.jar;" com.mycompany.app.App` и проверь, чтобы запуск был из корня проекта.